# How to capture enough energy from a 433 MHz RF signal to activate a transistor?

Tags: power, rf, lora

I have some battery-powered devices in a LoRa network with a custom gateway (my own PCBs) and was wondering if it's possible for the gateway to wake the other devices using a modulated 433 MHz signal (this is legal to use in the UK and also the same frequency our LoRa transceivers use, so the same antennas etc.)

My plan is to activate a transistor/MOSFET on the devices to wake them, then they will all send data and return to sleep. The advantage for me is that the gateway itself will also be able to sleep instead of remaining awake for readings to appear. I have considered synchronizing the devices but they currently do not have RTC chips, or accurate RTCs in their MCUs, so drift would occur and the gateway would need to cover a wider window to capture all of the data reliably.

Comment: Some bit has to be awake...

Comment: Is the data collection unit the "master" and, the remote slaves are really only needing to send data? Please explain in case you are trying to solve an XY problem.

Comment: If it wakes up with ANY 433MHz around, it might be less efficient than an actual low power arrangement. (depending on stray 433MHz signals)

Comment: Which LoRa transceivers are you using? How far away are they from the gateway?

Comment: To expand, the LoRa gateway and sensors are within around 1/2 mile of eachother, and well away from any other significant sources of RF (except the sun). My plan is for the RF signal to trigger a sensitive circuit to initially activate a FET to power up the sensor device, which then latches the FET using a GPIO to stay active until it has sent data, then release the gate to return to power down completely. It seems like the power required would be too high though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *might* be possible using a very high Q LC arrangement tuned to 433MHz such that it's voltage rises high enough to turn on an IGFET. However, any signal at that frequency might also trigger it. You will still need a battery for the data transmission.
Try it.

Comment: Thanks, yes, the sensor devices do have batteries - it's really a question of whether they could be woken using the RF signal with a sensitive passive receiver circuit - or at least using minimal power to receive. After waking, the sensor device will latch a MOSFET to remain powered until data is sent. These devices are in a very remote location, so unlikely to encounter other 433mhz signals. We are using satellite to upload data as no GSM either.

Answer (score 1):

There's passively powered RFID tags, but they aren't LoRa devices, and it all works on much shorter distances than LoRa.

It's not hard to calculate through Free Space Path Loss that remote power up of circuits on 433 MHz will require illegally high transmit power for anything further than a few meters away.

If you want LoRa, you'll need a battery. But all these LPWAN devices are typically optimized for battery operation. Lest you attach something less power-saving to the same battery, there's a lot of things that will work literally a decade on a coin cell.

Comment: Thanks yes I use RFID/NFC etc on other projects. I've been using LoRa/LPWAN for a couple of years but normally with a gateway that's constantly available on mains power. This is a situation where the gateway itself is also battery powered, and so it's more efficient if the gateway can sleep and somehow wake the remote sensors when needed.